# Isobaric Process: Change in Internal Energy vs Initial and Final Internal Energy

Tags: thermodynamics

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzmXVvxXN70&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezenMichelvanBiezen

Hypothesis: Initial internal energy of an isobaric process always 0 because it is a state process

In reviewing thermodynamic processes, it is common to see the change in internal energy and not to separately calculate final and initial internal energy. Is it because of the hypothesis I posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only differences between internal energy are of concern, so in the process we evaluate the difference in internal energy, which is not the same as assuming the initial internal energy is zero.  An earlier question/response address the absolute value of internal energy: see [Can mass-energy equivalence be used to measure absolute internal energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598694/can-mass-energy-equivalence-be-used-to-measure-absolute-internal-energy) on this exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The internal energy does change in an isobaric process, so your hypothesis is incorrect.  Your video confirms this.